# Wordpress DB structure

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to create more pages in wordpress via running a script. I am new in wordpress and did not understand the wordpress db structure properly. Where I put the page name, link, image and other details?
Can u please tell me the db structure of wordpress?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Searching Google for "*wordpress db structure*"](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=wordpress+db+structure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete wordpress database structure [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)

page,link,image all or must be in **posts** table.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that in wp_posts table. You should find it in the database you create it to install the WP for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

It even has links to old versions.

depending on what you might want to add you may have to add things to wp_posts and wp_postmeta, and possibly the taxonomy tables.